# How to check if part of an array is true and then return a seperate part of array?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this array:

```
"address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "#7",
        "short_name" : "#7",
        "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "23",
        "short_name" : "23",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Bedford Road",
        "short_name" : "Bedford Rd",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Lexington",
        "short_name" : "Lexington",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "California",
        "short_name" : "CA",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "United States",
        "short_name" : "US",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "02435",
        "short_name" : "02435",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
     }
  ],
```

And this code:

```
foreach ('address_components' as $type) {
  if ($type['types'] = 'administrative_area_level_1') {
    $state = $type['short_name'];
  }
}
```

I'm trying to loop through the array and check if the type matches administrative area level 1 and if it does return the value of that part's short name. The code I have so far is only returning the first item in the array.

Thanks.

Comment: To check if value in array - use `in_array` function.

Comment: For one thing, you're using `=` in your `if` condition, where I'm guessing you meant to use `==`.

Comment: Wow. Um this is embarassing. I didn't even notice that I left out the = sign. That button on the keyboard has been working only on and off lately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is false. Change

```
if ($type['types'] = 'administrative_area_level_1') // ....
```

To

```
 if ($type['types'] == 'administrative_area_level_1')
```

Because  `if ($type['types'] = 'administrative_area_level_1')` is true.

You set $type['types'] with the value : administrative_area_level_1 so it's normal to return true.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. It was a stupid mistake. Keyboard isn't working well. I don't know how I missed that.